# Does Cloud SQL have a query console or is CLI the only option?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I see an online environment for BigQuery but not for Cloud SQL; am I just missing it or should all queries be executed via cloud-sdk on CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, for now there is no UI for executing SQL queries in a Cloud SQL instance and you can use the Cloud SQL or maybe connect to the DB using MySQL Workbench for MySQL or any other third-party product (this also apply for the other DB flavors).

Answer (score 1):

All depends on the meaning of "query".

- If you want to update, insert, delete data or schema in Cloud SQL instance, YES, the CLI is the only option (or you can create a connexion with [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) on your side and connect your database client on it. Or also, you can [authorize your public IP in the Cloud SQL authorized network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks) and directly use the public IP of your Cloud SQL instance in your database client tool)
- If you want to only SELECT data in your Cloud SQL instance (MySQL and Postgres, not yet with SQL Server), you can use [BigQuery and the external table connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) to achieve this. And thus use BigQuery UI to query your database.